# Freeing memory for a pointer to struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, free

I have the following piece of code that I cannot change

```
typedef struct 
{
    char* firstName;
    char* lastName;
    int id;
    float mark;
}* pStudentRecord;
```

Now I am allocating memory in the following way:

```
g_ppRecords = (pStudentRecord*) malloc (sizeof(pStudentRecord*) *(g_numRecords));       /*allocate required memory for the array of pointers to instances of pStudentRecord*/

/*populate the data structure with records from the text file*/
while (count<g_numRecords)
{   
    fscanf(g_pf,"%s %s %i %f\n",&fn,&ln,&i,&m);

    /*allocate memory for each student record. the pointer to each of these will be stored in the array g_ppRecords*/
    g_ppRecords[count]=(pStudentRecord)malloc(sizeof(char*)*2+sizeof(int)+sizeof(float));

    /*allocate memory for the firstName and lastName on the heap for each record. use only as much space as is required*/
    g_ppRecords[count]->firstName=(char*)malloc(strlen(fn));
    g_ppRecords[count]->lastName=(char*)malloc(strlen(ln));

    /*assign values stored in local variables to the ones on heap for each record*/
    strcpy(g_ppRecords[count]->firstName,fn);
    strcpy(g_ppRecords[count]->lastName,ln);
    g_ppRecords[count]->id=i;
    g_ppRecords[count]->mark=m;

    ++count; /*onto next record*/
}
```

However I am having trouble freeing it . This is what I am doing:

```
while (count<g_numRecords)
{
        /*copy variables in the struct instance into local variables*/
    strcpy(fn,g_ppRecords[count]->firstName);
    strcpy(ln,g_ppRecords[count]->lastName);
    id=g_ppRecords[count]->id;
    mark=g_ppRecords[count]->mark;

    free(g_ppRecords[count]->firstName);
    g_ppRecords[count]->firstName=NULL;
    free(g_ppRecords[count]->lastName);
    g_ppRecords[count]->lastName=NULL;
    free(g_ppRecords[count]);

    ++count;

    #ifdef DEBUG
        printf("\n%s %s %d %.2f",fn,ln,id,mark);
    #endif

    /*detect any errors while writing to file*/
    if(fprintf(g_pf,"%s %s %d %.2f\n",fn,ln,id,mark) ==-1)
        perror("");
    else{
        #ifdef DEBUG
            printf("success");
        #endif
    }

    #ifdef DEBUG
        printf("return val=%d",now);
    #endif
}

    free(g_ppRecords);  /*free memory after writing to file is complete*/
    g_ppRecords=NULL;   /*make pointer point to NULL*/
    fclose(g_pf);       /*close file stream*/
}
```

I know it might be related to allocating memory as:

```
g_ppRecords[count]=(pStudentRecord)malloc(sizeof(char*)*2+sizeof(int)+sizeof(float));
```

but I am unable to allocate it as

```
g_ppRecords[count]=(pStudentRecord)malloc(sizeof(pStudentRecord));
```

Plz help !

Comment: Are you sure `pStudentRecord` should have that last `*` in it?

Comment: u mean in here ?  
    g_ppRecords=(pStudentRecord*) malloc (sizeof(pStudentRecord*) *(g_numRecords));

Comment: yes that is provided by the prof and it has to be there ! i cannot use malloc (sizeof (pStudentRecord) ) coz of that...

Comment: "but I am unable to allocate it as .."  whats the the actual problem ? any error message?

Comment: wow ! i am actually able to do
    g_ppRecords[count]=(pStudentRecord)malloc(sizeof(pStudentRecord));
but i still get the runtime crash. really dont know whats going on

tried allocating g_ppRecords[count]->firstName=(char*)malloc(strlen(fn)+1);

instead of 

g_ppRecords[count]->firstName=(char*)malloc(strlen(fn));
(as i later on do a strcpy and that would add a \0 char ..

but that did not help either

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look like:

```
typedef struct 
{
    char* firstName;
    char* lastName;
    int id;
    float mark;
} StudentRecord;

/* Allocate memory for each student record. */
g_ppRecords[count] = (StudentRecord*)malloc(sizeof(StudentRecord));

/* Allocate memory for the firstName and lastName on the heap. */
g_ppRecords[count]->firstName = (char*)malloc(strlen(fn)+1);
g_ppRecords[count]->lastName = (char*)malloc(strlen(ln)+1);
```

You are not allocating space for the training zeroes in the strings and this corrupts the memory. It is better to use `sizeof(struct)` when you allocate space for the record itself. This struct may have some paddings between the fields or after the whole record that are potentially not included into your calculation of the size.

If you cannot change your header, you should write:

```
pStudentRecord DummyPtrVar;
g_ppRecords = (pStudentRecord*)malloc(sizeof(*DummyPtrVar)*g_numRecords);
```

Writing `pStudentRecord*` under sizeof is incorrect. This will create double-pointer instead of accessing the record itself. C/C++ does not allow simple access to the pointed type. But if you define a variable, you can make a pseudo-dereference. This is not neat but I am sure will work with 99% of compilers.

Comment: Hey Kirill, i tried those things .. but my application still cannot free memory for first and last Name for instances of pStudentRecord.

I am not allowed to change the declaration of the struct. Its a code I must use as is.

Answer (score 0):

I think main problem of your code is the allocate of g_ppRecords,

```
"g_ppRecords = (pStudentRecord*) malloc (sizeof(pStudentRecord*) *(g_numRecords));"
```

should change to

```
"g_ppRecords = (pStudentRecord*) malloc (sizeof(pStudentRecord) *(g_numRecords));"
```

of course, as @Kirill says,char array should leave a more byte to contain '\n'.

Comment: But i need the array to be an array of pointers to pStudentRecord and not the structs themselves .. u still say i should change it ?